# How to Record the Screen of devices below the lollipop

Tags: java, android

I have used this code to record the screen but it's creating the file video file with 0kb size.

```
Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh");
DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

outputStream.writeBytes("screenrecord --time-limit 10 /sdcard/MyVideo.mp4\n");
outputStream.flush();

outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
su.waitFor();
su.exitValue();
su.destroy();
```

Comment: when i play the recorded video its give the error "Can't play" this video

Comment: if any ios developer to help which is work on android or have any concept to help record the device screen

Comment: You should collect stderr from the command to see why it's failing. Unless this is running as `root` or `shell`, it'll fail due to permissions.

Comment: yes i have give the super user permissio also